# pyhocon - force a variable to have float type (instead of str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration

I'm using `pyhocon` package and I want one of the parameters to be given as a int/int division. The conf file looks something like:

```
{
  var = 1/3
}
```

However, this is what I get for trying:

```
>>> from pyhocon import ConfigFactory
>>> conf = ConfigFactory.parse_file(conf_path)
>>> conf.var
 '1/3'
>>> conf.get_float('var')
pyhocon.exceptions.ConfigException: var has type 'str' rather than 'float'
```

How can I force `var` to have float type? (without using some kind of `eval`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3/4` is not a float. `0.75` is. You would need to "calculate" your string first.

Use

```
{
  var = 0.75
}
```

instead.

---

Alternatively:

```
import operator  

k =  operator.truediv( *map(int,"3/4".split("/")))  # conf.var
print(k)
```

to get to `0.75`

Comment: you are correct with the specific choice of 3/4. that's not what I meant. I've updated it. so for 1/3 you won't be able to do the first "trick"

Comment: this is no "trick" - the closest a float can get to `1/3` is `0.33333333333` .. with some more 3 in it. you get that by `operator.truediv( *map(int,"1/3".split("/")))` ... if you want to use _real_ `fractions` see my other answer.

Comment: it's not "some more 3", it's inifinite times more 3. even if you say float is finite I still don't want to be dependent on the float representation in the machine, or type the whole decimal representation every time I change the parameter. but really, it's just over-complicating my question. your "alternatively" part was what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably eval is the simplest

```py
In [3]: conf['var'] = eval(conf['var'])  
In [4]: conf.get_float('var')                                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: 0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) in your program, use the correct datatype for it:

```
import fractions 

k =  fractions.Fraction( "1/3" )  # you use conf.var instead of '1/3'  
print(k)
print(float(k))
```

Output:

```
Fraction(1, 3)  
0.3333333333333333
```

[`fraction.Fraction(string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) works for your `conf.var`